# Selfsigned certificate is shown as not trusted source in signTool

Tags: powershell, signtool

I make my own certificate with signTool like

```
powershell.exe New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "www.mydns.me" -Type CodeSigning -NotBefore 27.10.2021 -NotAfter 27.10.2024 -CertStoreLocation "cert:\CurrentUser\My"
```

The certificate is availabe in certificate manager
I signed my file with

```
signtool sign /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com /td sha256 /fd sha256 /a myfile.exe
```

I want to show certificates on the file  with

```
signtool verify /pa  myfile.exe
```

but it gave the source is not trusted
SignTool Error: A certificate chain processed, but terminated in a root
certificate which is not trusted by the trust provider.

Why is certificate not trusted when the option is /pa and is available in my certificate center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The self signed certificate is **self-signed** and stored in your current user certificate `Personal` store.
This is not because you have the certificate that you trust it or the computer trust it.
You must import a copy of this certificate in the `Trusted Root Certification Authorities`. You can import it in the user store or computer store (any user on the local machine would trust your self signed certificate).
Use by example `Import-Certificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\CurrentUser\Root -FilePath C:\cert.cer`. Only the `public` key must be imported in the `Trusted Root Certification Authorities` store and not the `private` key.

I don't know for the `/pa` option. Try without any option.